# How we call Fragment from this java class?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have to call fragment from this class and also want to send Array list in fragment
    I am Storing firebase notification in arraylist

```
public class DataManager{

    private static volatile DataManager dataManager;

    public DataManager() {

    }

    public static DataManager factory() {
        if (dataManager == null) {
            synchronized (DataManager.class) {
                if (dataManager == null) {
                    dataManager = new DataManager();
                }
            }
            dataManager = new DataManager();
        }
        return dataManager;
    }

    public ArrayList<NotIfModel> notIfArray = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Comment: Please send your Activity code.

Comment: you can't call it from this how it is now. You have to get a Context somewhere. SO you can pass a context to this class, or call fragment from the other class

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
public DataManager(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {        
   Fragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
   fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
}
```